# Get a default value of the Customizer setting using wp.customize API (JS)

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, api

Is it possible to get a default value that was set in the Customizer setting? Here is an example of the code:

```
// Add setting.
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'slug_awesome_title', array(
    'default' => esc_html__( 'WordPress', 'slug' ),
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
) );

// Add control.
$wp_customize->add_control( 'slug_awesome_title', array(
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Section Title', 'slug' ),
    'section' => 'slug_awesome_section',
    'type' => 'text',
) );
```

If the current control has already a set value, let's say it's "WooCommerce", how can I get a default value which is set to "WordPress" using wp.customize API in JS?

I've tried this:

```
wp.customize.instance( 'slug_awesome_title' ).get()
```

but it returns the current value of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make sense for the default value to be available via:

```
wp.customize.instance( 'slug_awesome_title' ).default
```

Or equivalently:

```
wp.customize( 'slug_awesome_title' ).default
```

However, I can see the `default` is simply not getting exported from PHP to JS. I can see that this is going to be needed in core also when client-side templating replaces server-side rendering of controls in [#30738](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30738), so a [core patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/30738/export-setting-defaults.diff) would be needed.

Nevertheless, in the mean time you can add the following PHP to export your `default` value onto the JS `Setting` object to have mostly the same effect:

```
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    global $wp_customize;
    wp_add_inline_script( 'customize-controls', sprintf(
        'wp.customize( "slug_awesome_title", function ( setting ) { setting.default = %s; } );',
        wp_json_encode( $wp_customize->get_setting( 'slug_awesome_title' )->default )
    ) );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all default settings by calling the object:

```
wp.customize.settings.values
```

For example:

```
// Enqueue live preview javascript in Theme Customizer admin screen
wp.customize( 'my_control', function( value ) {

    console.log( "default: ", wp.customize.settings.values.my_control );

    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        // ....
    } );
} );
```

Comment: `wp.customize.settings.values.my_control` will return current value, not default value.